# How to not Load Google Charts in Offline mode

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net-mvc-4, google-visualization

I am building an MVC 4 web application and using Google Charts, the thing is, it won't be all the time online, so i would like to know if there is a way to check if http://www.google.com/jsapi is accessible  to load or not the charts, or if there is a way around to not load the charts like a condition in javascript.

Comment: this not looking possible see faq link https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/faq?csw=1#offline

Comment: yes i read it, what i am trying to do is hide the area where the charts would be in offline mode :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using

```
if (navigator.onLine) {
  alert('online')
} else {
  alert('offline');
  //use jquery to hide the chart div using css
}
```

Or You could use jQuery to perform an ajax call to a page you own, and if its succesful you are online, otherwise its offline then use jQuery to hide the chart div.

Answer (score 2):

```
You can't use Google Chart Tools offline. 
You can find another library which you need.
pChart etc
```

Comment: Thanks, but like i said i don't want to have charts while offline.